# Django "type object X has no attribute POST"

Tags: python, django

For some reason, I cannot do this without result in an error. How does TodoForm have no attribute to POST? All the other example shows it's valid.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Todo
from .forms import TodoForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def todoPanel(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TodoForm.POST(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('steve') 
    else:
        form = TodoForm()

    return render(request, 'todo_panel.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It should be `TodoForm(request.POST)` not `TodoForm.POST(request.POST)`...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your line

```py
form = TodoForm.POST(request.POST)
```

to:

```py
form = TodoForm(request.POST)
```